# check Mysql with remote host - Icinga2

Tags: mysql, remote-access, remote-server, icinga2

I'm using Icinga2 to monitor Mysql server on a remote host.Now, I'm trying to configure a `mysql_check`.

Here is the file `service.conf` :

```
apply Service "mysql8" {  
  import "generic-service"
 check_command = "mysql"

 vars.mysql_mode = "uptime"
 vars.mysql_hostname = "remote-host"
 vars.mysql_port = "3306"
 vars.mysql_username = "username"
 vars.myql_password = "password"
 command_endpoint = host.vars.client_endpoint
 assign where host.vars.mysql == true && host.vars.client_endpoint
}
```

Here is the file `host.conf` :

```
object Host "remote-host" {
import "generic-host"
address = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx"
vars.os = "linux"
vars.mysql = true
host.vars.client_endpoint="remote-host"
```

When I try a `check_MySQL`from Icinga2, I got the following error :

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'remote-host' (111)

What can I do to resolve the `check_MySQL` with the remote-host.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice to find you here.

I think that your mysql server doesn't allow the remote access.

In this case :

1. Open a command prompt and run the following command to open the SSH tunnel.

   $ ssh user@example.com -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
   NB. Replace `user@example.com` with your ssh username and your ssh hostname or IP adress.

-N : forwarding port

-L : binds a local port to the remote host port
2. Try to connect with your mysql-client

```
$ mysql --protocol TCP -h localhost -u YOUR_MYSQL_USER -P 3307 -p
```

It's work? So, :)

3. Just replace `vars.mysql_port=3307` in your icinga service configuration.

Great! great stuff! no ?